# Finding basis which is non stable under finite intersection

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry, while talking about sheaves. We want to extend a sheaf on a basis $\mathcal B$ of a topological space $X$, to a sheaf on $X$.

They usually say that $\mathcal B$ is stable under finite intersection.

My problem is since we have a basis for topology, for every open set $U$ of $X$, if you intersect with a basis element it is again a basis element so why do they explicitly say it is stable under finite intersection? Is there some counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are counterexamples. Consider, for instance, the basis of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The intersection of two balls is, in general, not a ball anymore.